# Segmentation fault for string based argument

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to make a password generating program that automates the process I use to generate passwords. (Inspiration: [Password algorithm (by a Turing winner)](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2978316/security/tired-of-memorizing-passwords-a-turing-award-winner-came-up-with-this-algorithmic-trick.html)
I'm writing it using CodeBlocks. 
However when I run it via the terminal (by cd'ing into the bin/Debug dir.) I get: 

    `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

From what I've read so far, it seems like I'm trying to access memory that I cannot. I'm fairly new to pointer so I'm not sure what to do.

I tried adding a check to make sure that I have the required amount of arguments. But that still doesn't work.
Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int reverseString (char *X);
void switchVal (char &X, char &Y);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    string name, service;

    //Check if there are at least 2 arguments
    if (argc < 3)
    {
        cerr << "usage: ./PasswordManager USERNAME SERVICE" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    //Assign arguments to appropriate variables
    name    = argv[1];
    service = argv[2];

    reverseString(&name[0]);

    cout << name << endl;
}

int reverseString (char *X)
{
    int i, size;

    for (size=0; X[size]!='\0'; size++);
    size -= 1;

    for (i=0; i!=size; i++)
    {
        switchVal (X[i], X[size]);
        size--;
    }
    return 0;
}

void switchVal (char &X, char &Y)
{
    X = X + Y;
    Y = X - Y;
    X = X - Y;
}
```

Even more confusing is that when I change the argument in main `reverseString(&name[0])` to `reverseString(&name[1])` it works. Though the first alphabet remains the same. So I'm guessing it has something to do with that function/argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it to run. It only works if the first argument has an odd number of characters (Which kinda sucks). I'm working on fixing the loop that replaces characters.

Comment: Fixed! Changed the loop to: `for (i=0; i<size; i++)`

Comment: Please mark your own answer as the correct one, that's the process :)